# Cannot find method for data binding event using lambda

Tags: android, data-binding, lambda, kotlin, android-databinding

I have events working up to this point using the :: notation (i.e `android:onClick="@{vm::doIt}"`) but this requires the signature of `doIt` to have the unnecessary `View` parameter, which I end up ignoring the unused warning on. I'm trying to clean that up and move to the lambda event notation (i.e. `android:onClick="@{() -> vm.doIt()}, however the compiler throws an exception.

**layout.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.myapp.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> vm.buttonClicked()}"
            <!--android:onClick="@{vm::buttonClicked}" worked with view param in buttonClicked in the viewModel -->
            android:text="@{vm.buttonText}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
class ViewModel(): BaseObservable{

    //Bindings - All works great!

    //Event handler... not found, worked with commented param and :: notation
    fun buttonClicked(/*view: View*/){
        //Do button click stuff
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find method buttonClicked on ViewDataBinding file:/Users/.../app/src/main/res/layout/layout.xml loc:107:31 - 107:57 ****\ data binding error ****

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find method buttonClicked on ViewDataBinding file:/Users/.../app/src/main/res/layout/layout.xml loc:107:31 - 107:57 ****\ data binding error ****

at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:112)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1033)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1198)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:73)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the data binding generated classes were in a bad state and weren't getting properly regenerated, invalidating caches and cleaning fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

As you noted in your comment about the `android:onClick="@{vm::doIt}"` solution, your onClick handler must have a `View` parameter, even if you don't use it.

Your workaround of calling your parameter-less `buttonClicked` method via a lambda will work nicely, *so long as the lambda accepts the `View` parameter*. This is easy. [Unused parameters to lambdas can be named "_"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11) for clarity.  So your onClick handler can be configured thus:

```
android:onClick="@{_ -> vm.buttonClicked()}"
```

Comment: Changing the lambda as you recommend results in the same error.

Comment: not sure, but maybe `android:onClick="@{_: View-> vm.buttonClicked()}"` will do

Comment: Shouldn't need to. I think the error is solved now though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308716/3195526

Comment: @PaulHicks the `View` parameter refers to the view being clicked?

Comment: That's how I read it. I know nothing about Android SDKs though, I just know how to have an anonymous parameter to a lambda in Kotlin :)

Answer (score 3):

the signature of the method has to be the same in the viewModel,

I was using

```
android:onClick="@{v -> viewModel.settingsClick()}"
```

and the method in the viewModel was

```
 public void settingsClick() {
   ...
}
```